# MongoDb query by _id using Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

```
  const cCurser = await client
    .db("Database")
    .collection("Collection")
    .findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(Filter)       
    }).then(function(item){
        Obj = item;}
    );
```

I'm trying to query the MongoDB by the _id but it returns Promise {  }. please help me to retrieve the data in it.
`Error detected:ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this before your query:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Types;
```

OR:

use this:

```
  const cCurser = await client
    .db("Database")
    .collection("Collection")
    .findOne({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(Filter)       
    }).then(function(item){
        Obj = item;}
    );
```

Comment: I'm using the mongoose library, is there anything I can do without a mongoose. sorry for As Im new to Mongo

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't mix `await` syntax with the `then` syntax.

Either use `await`

```
let Obj = null;
const cCurser = await client
    .db("Database")
    .collection("Collection")
    .findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(Filter)       
    });

//Use Obj
```

Or the `then` syntax. Here you will have to write the rest of the code dependent on `Obj` inside `then()`.

```
let Obj = null;
const cCurser = client
    .db("Database")
    .collection("Collection")
    .findOne({
        _id: ObjectId(Filter)       
    }).then(function(item){
        Obj = item;
         //Use Obj
        }
    );
```

Also based on your edit,it seems you have not imported `ObjectId` method from Mongo.

````
let mongo = require('mongodb');
let ObjectId = mongo .ObjectID
```
````

Comment: I changed according to your instructions still I'm getting  Error detected:ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined